# Как сделать, чтобы бот не упоминал пользователей в telebot

Tags: python, telegram-bot, telegram, telebot, python-telegram-bot

Создал бота на `python telebot` и столкнулся с проблемой.

Я создал статистику по сообщениям и делаю ссылки на пользователей: в тексте был их профиль, при нажатии на текст переход на профиль этого пользователя.

Всё работает, но когда я пишу команду статистики, бот упоминает пользователей, когда возле имени чата пишет `@`.

Можно ли это как-то убрать?
Для ссылки я использую
`link = f"[{nm}](tg://user?id={usid})"`
и `parsemode="Markdown"`